# Where to find incremental version of OpenJDK 1.6.0_24?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, java-6

I have two EC2 instances, Development and Production.

Checking the java version on each gives the following:

Development

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.11) (amazon-61.1.11.11.53.amzn1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

Production

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.11.90) (amazon-62.1.11.11.90.55.amzn1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

The versions of Java are identical (`1.6.0_24`) but have a minor difference:

Development: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.11) (amazon-61.1.11.11.**53.amzn1-x86_64**)

Production: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.11.**90**) (amazon-62.1.11.11.**90.55.amzn1-x86_64**)

Keeping the dev and prod environments synchronized is key.  In the hopes of not having to modify both environments, my goal is to modify development to match production.

Because of the similarity in the version number, I'm having trouble finding an RPM or archive that will give me an incremental version that matches productions.

Do you have any tips or ideas on finding a reliable source that explicitly gives the incremental version for `java-1.6.0-openjdk`?

I'm including AWS tags in the event this issue is specific to that environment.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some input from a coworker and a bit more digging, I found the answer.  I should have tagged this question with yum!

Running `yum info java-1.6.0-openjdk` showed the version installed and the available update (edited for brevity):

```
yum info java-1.6.0-openjdk
Installed Packages
Name        : java-1.6.0-openjdk
Version     : 1.6.0.0
Release     : 61.1.11.11.53.amzn1

Available Packages
Name        : java-1.6.0-openjdk
Version     : 1.6.0.0
Release     : 62.1.11.11.90.55.amzn1
```

Running `yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk` brought the dev system to the desired state.

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.11.90) (amazon-62.1.11.11.90.55.amzn1-x86_64)
```

Cheers,

Michael J

Answer (score 0):

Check here of IceTea project detail, http://icedtea.classpath.org/wiki/Main_Page#Getting_IcedTea

In the 'Getting IceTea' section, you can find a Download link of this,
http://icedtea.wildebeest.org/download/